# Get REQUEST_URI and don't overwrite

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

I tried storing the REQUEST_URI in a session with the code below. I need to store the very first REQUEST_URI when a visitor lands on a page on our site and not have it overwritten when they begin browsing pages. This isn't working as I browse the site i'm seeing a new URI displayed by the echo.

```
session_start();
if ( !isset( $_SESSION['theuri'] ) ) {
    if ( !empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
        $_SESSION['theuri'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
}

echo $_SESSION['theuri'];
```

Comment: You code is valid. There must be something (timeout, no cookies, sessionpath now writeable) with your session handler. Do you have a custom session handler?

Comment: @John I found this snippet on stack and made a tiny mod to get the URI rather than referrer. I'm sure the session save path is fine. Cookies are setting as well.

Comment: @John I double checked the session save path /tmp it's writeable

Comment: And the client accepts cookies?

Comment: @BjørneMalmanger yes cookies are enabled

Comment: Without more research/information this question wont get more than just guesses.

Comment: @John it's on my WordPress site placed into the footer if that matters

Comment: @John, even if they used a non-standard handler, the standard handler should still work, no?

Comment: @John so is there another function that can do what I need?

Comment: Yes, see my answer, you sart the session in the footer, so cookies cannot be set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article which said to add this code to my functions.php and now the code in my footer is working fine.

http://devondev.com/2012/02/03/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cookie and try again.  It was probably set the first time when you never had the !empty() conditional and never changed since

Answer (score 0):

You might try this hack:

```
if(session_id() == '') 
     session_start();
```

Should help if WP tries to start session for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must start the session before any output so the cookies can be set correctly.
Wordpress is stateless and uses no sessions at all.
You mention you put this code in the footer, so probably there is output already.

A hacky solution would be to enter session_start() on the top of your index.php, or in wp-config.php.

Comment: I tried putting the session_start() at the very top of my index, even before the header function. Still not saving.

Comment: did you remove session_start from the footer? And session_start is in index.php now? And if you put your code in a testfile, test.php, does it work correctly then (instead of the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] use time())?

Comment: See my answer I needed to add some code into my theme functions, it's working now

Comment: Session start is now in my functions.php